# Is it right? time < 0?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I'm doing the solutions of Halliday's book kinematic exercise, given the equation of acceleration:$$a(t) = -30t.$$
One wonders when the acceleration is positive. [In a resolution](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIGqgf3VJHY), says that for t < 0. But it is correct to say **"negative time"**?

Comment: hoping that you understood the equation : negative time, relative to its conventional origin, is not a problem.

Comment: In this context, negative time means the time before the experiment\process started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the time coordinate $t$ of an event, just like the value of its spatial coordinates $x,y,z$ is unimportant, totally arbitrary and differs from one observer to another. What does not change however,(at least in classical mechanics) is the spatial separation $\Delta x$ between two events and the time interval $\Delta t$ that separates them. By convention, we use $t=0$ to mean "the instant you started to observe a set of events", but we could have chosen any other value for $t$ and it will work.

Say, Your friend started to watch some car moving beginning from $t=0$, And then you came after 10 seconds to join him in watching this car. Now according to you, how long has the car been moving since you joined in? well since you've just came, then your $t'=0$, but when did your friend started to watch the car? well about 10 seconds ago(according to you), which translates in your coordinates to $t'=-10$. But the crucial point to realize is if I asked you How long has the car been moving since the moment your friend started to watch it and the moment you joined in? in your coordinates this is equal to $\Delta t'= t'_{final} -t'_{initial}= (0)-(-10)=10 $ seconds. What about your friend? he will say $\Delta t= t_{final} -t_{initial}= (10)-(0)=10 $ seconds.

So yes, there's no problem with $t$ being negative.